# Do you have to be a Chabadnick to follow the Shulchan Aruch Harav?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, chabad, mishnah-berurah

If I'm a bred and born ashkenazic male, who's been taught to follow the Mishna Brurahs Psakim all his life. Would it be significantly different to follow more or less by the Shulchan Aruch Harav? Leaving aside Minhagim issues.

Comment: You should have been taught to follow your rabbi's rulings.

Comment: Who's considered my Rabbi? @DoubleAA

Comment: I obviously don't know since I don't know you... Who do you ask questions to? Perhaps the rabbi of your Shul? Perhaps a close teacher?

Comment: related: [How should one decide which Halacha to follow?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/72993/11501)

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26359/do-other-chasidic-communities-follow-shulchan-aruch-harav?rq=1

Comment: What is your family's custom?

Comment: The maggid of mezritch asked the alter rebbe to write this for chassidim. It wasn't written specifically for chabad chassidim. Later on the alter rebbe changed his mind on certain things and made changes specific for chabad chassidim in the siddur and in other writings

Comment: You can't be much older than sixty if you were taught to follow piskei Mishnah Berurah your whole life. Prior to the Shoah and for about a decade thereafter, the Kitzur Shulchan 'Aruch was much more widely-accepted than the M"B and is still used by a wide subset of Ashkenazi communities (Jekkes, Chabad, some other chassidim, Hungarian non-chassidim)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Historically Lithuanian Jews followed  Chaiya Adam until fairly recently. Polish Jews followed the SA HaRav. The MB gained halachic reign sometime after 1980. Ask anyone over 40 who is ffb what they learned halacha from as a teen. We are not bound to follow the MB even though he is one of the greatest commentaries to SA OH and aside for halacha kBasrei.

Comment: Shkoaich @StevenEdelstein

Comment: Historically Lithuanian Jews followed the Beer Hetev until fairly recently. Then the Chayei Adam gained prominence. We are not bound to follow the CA even though he is a great work

Comment: @DoubleAA Lithuanian Jews followed the aruch hashulchan

Comment: True . I grew up learning zichru toras Mosha from the chayi Adam for hilchos Shabus. Aruch hashulchan was for the big boys and SA was for the real players.

Comment: @Asher I was just parodying the ridiculous claim that whole countries followed one book for all things.

Comment: Measuring the Geographic Similarity of Poskim https://blog.hamapah.org/metrics/measuring-the-geographic-similarity-of-poskim/

Answer (score 1):

When the alter rebbe made shulchan aruch harav he made it for everyone (btw he made it becuase the maggid of mezritch told him to do it, and the vilnan gaon wanted to make a shulchan aruch he didnt, and he said its because he didnt get permission from shamayim) 
in the back of shulchan aruch harav there is "piskei hasiddur" which was written later by the alter rebbe for chabbad chassidim, his shulchan aruch was for all yiddden.

Even if you dont follow shulchan aruch harav, i suggest you learn it just because its such a monumental work, and you could be medayik in his lashon to see who he holds like, who he is negating etc.

Answer (score 0):

I added the "Hashkofoh" tag to the question because it is not Halachic per-se.

Following Halacha is not about the amount of Halochos but about  one specific approach. So one who follows only Kulos (lenient) Psakim of several Poskim just as one who follows the Chumrot (stringencies) of different Poskim, are both fools.

It is more common with Baalei Teshuva that have no family tradition choosing their way in Judaism. I did it once and my Rabbi Z"l advised me to choose freely but eventually lock on one approach.

For those who have a family tradition, esp on the father's side, one has to follow it under "שמע בני מוסר אביך". In such a case, switching from M"B to ShuA Harav might raise the question of breaking a vow (as the tradition is considered sort of a vow).

To sum it up - one can either "convert" to Chabad (probably requires a simple התרת נדרים) and then follow the ShuA Harav in full or use the ShuA"H as a reference for resolving Halachic disputes (as most Ashkenazi do) but not follow it in cases that contradict the MB.